# laravel 5.8 и morphMany

Tags: php, laravel, полиморфизм

В [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations) описано как должны выглядить модели как из них получать, а вот не показанно как их записывать, я пробовал через `attach` но позже я понял что это относиться к `morphToMany` вот так выглядит функция в модели "Cites"

```
public function comments(){
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
```

Так выглядит часть в CitesController:

```
$city->update($request->all());
//Вот как тут правильно записывать?
$city->comments()->save(['body' = 'sdsad']);
```

Comment: Некоторые связи используют промежуточную таблицу, ваша полиморфная связь ко многим должна использовать промежуточную таблицу.
Вы создаёте две записи и вписываете - **$city->comments()->attach($comment_id);** , либо передаёте объект $comment полностью в attach. **$comment = new Comment; $comment->name = "test"; $comment->save(); $city->comments()->attach($comment);**

Comment: Method attach not found @MoloF

Comment: 1) Можно увидеть всю задействованную структуру базы данных?
2) Метод покажите весь ваш код как вы используете метод ->attach();
3) Более развёрнутый вопрос даст более точный ответ.

Comment: в morphMany нету такого метода, Вы может путаете с morphToMany?